# Google-Maps and Play framework

Tags: google-maps, gps, location, playframework

The user should enter a valid adress and click ok. Then a Google-Map should be shown. Then the user shoult simply say ok(if the wright place is shown in the map) or he should be able to change the adress (if the wrong place is shown in the map), by entering a new adress or by moving the pin on the map.

Is this possible with play framework?
And how can i get the gps-coordinates of the selected point?

Kind regards, joe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done entirely client side using JavaScript and the GoogleMaps API, so you could build this in pure HTML if you wanted to! So, yes Play can easily support this.

Comment: and how can i get the coordinates in my play-database then?

Comment: use maps API to send an AJAX request to your server with the necessary information, which you can pick out of the Maps API, and implement a simple action on your server side to save that data (probably via a simple Model class).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible given that the Google Maps API let's you do it. This is not something limited by Play, which in itself it only helps you create websites, but by the Maps API and what you can do with it.

In other words, you could do this with Play, Lift, Struts, Ruby or your own framework.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this article/application using Scala, Play Framework and Google Maps--it might help you!
http://geeks.aretotally.in/location-based-play-framework-scala-google-maps-clustering-postgresql-and-anorm-appli